# Rest Service Call Redirected to Log in page

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I have web application A and B. A is my main application with spring security (authentication) enabled and B is a service to communication with external services. I'm trying to call A's rest service from B but what i got for my response was a log in page. Example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <body>...</body>
</html>
```

I'm actually getting a webpage and I don't know why it did that. What I should get is a Json string. I will appreciate any helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 way:

1. Bypass your authentication model for source B (not recommended)
2. Create a specific user for service B and call your request using the correct authentication.

In this way you can access your service without problem.

Comment: You mean like an application account for background processes? For instances, background database processes, rest calls, etc...

Comment: yes. exactly. you need to call a service which is need authentication. (I guess http-header or cookie based. so do it :)